# PHP Pattern Validation

Tags: php, regex, validation

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my pattern to validate the string entry correctly.  The PHP portion of this assignment is working correctly, so I won't include that here as to make this easier to read.  Can someone tell me why this pattern isn't matching what I'm trying to do?

This pattern has these validation requirements:

1. Should first have 3-6 lowercase letters
2. This is immediately followed by either a hyphen or a space
3. Followed by 1-3 digits

   ```
   $codecheck = '/^([[:lower:]]{3,6}-)|([[:lower:]]{3,6} ?)\d{1,3}$/';
   ```

Currently this catches most of the requirements, but it only seems to validate the minimum character requirements - and doesn't return false when more than 6 or 3 characters (respectively) are entered.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Instead of the "or" pipe, use [\s-] to look for a - or a space.

Comment: You don't need to duplicate the lower `/^[[:lower:]]{3,6}[\s-]\d{1,3}$/`

Comment: I don't think `design-patterns` tag is appropriate here. You should maybe use `regex` instead.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, please write it as an answer and not a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here lies in how you group the alternatives. Right now, the regex matches a string that

- `^([[:lower:]]{3,6}-)` - starts with 3-6 lowercase letters followed with a hyphen
- `|` - or
- `([[:lower:]]{3,6} ?)\d{1,3}$` - ends with 3-6 lowercase letters followed with an optional space and followed with 1-3 digits.

In fact, you can get rid of the alternation altogether:

```
$codecheck = '/^\p{Ll}{3,6}[- ]\d{1,3}$/';
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rH2mQ8/1)

*Explanation*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\p{Ll}{3,6}` - 3-6 lowercase letters
- `[- ]` - a positive character class matching one character, either a hyphen or a space
- `\d{1,3}` - 1-3 digits
- `$` - end of string

Comment: @Shaw: Just to clarify that your regex can work, too, once the alternations are placed into a  group: [`^(?:([[:lower:]]{3,6}-)|([[:lower:]]{3,6} ?))\d{1,3}$`](https://regex101.com/r/bI9xL9/1). However, it is not efficient.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - as I'm just learning it, it's good to know I was on the right track for educational purposes, but not yet seeing the whole picture in regards to efficiency.

Comment: When using alternation like this, backtracking is increasing the number of steps needed to return a match/or detect a non-matching string. See the green box showing number of steps with [your regex](https://regex101.com/r/mB3kR0/1) and [mine](https://regex101.com/r/rH2mQ8/1). Although that number of steps is not a direct indicator of performance, when the step count is doubled like in this case, it hints at performance difference between the two patterns.

Answer (score 2):

You need to delimit the scope of the `|` operator in the middle of your regex.

As it is now:

- the right-side argument of that OR runs up until the very end of your regex, even including the `$`. So the digits, ***nor*** the end-of-string condition do not apply for the left side of the `|`.
- the left-side argument of the OR starts with `^`, and ***only*** applies to the left side.

That is why you get a match when you supply 7 lowercase characters. The first character is ignored, and the rest matches with the right-side of the regex pattern.

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down!